# ejs view engine path setting issue in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, path, ejs

I have no idea how to draw the structure of my project here in stackoverflow, so I will try to explain what my issues are as clear as possible.

I have server.js file in my root, using express.static middleware.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and my style.css file is included in public/css/style.css

Also, I am using ejs view engine, and I have two view files.
(ejs view engine is looking for views folder)

First one is views/main/home.ejs, and second one is views/sub/intro/location.ejs

I`m using <% include %> code in each file,

```
// views/main/home.ejs
<% include ../header.ejs %>

// views/sub/intro/location.ejs
<% include ../../header.ejs %>
```

The problem is that, in header.ejs file, do I have to link same css file in two different href path? like,

```
// views/header.ejs

// for views/main/home.ejs
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">

// for views/sub/intro/location.ejs
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

Is that the only way I can do?

if header.ejs has many static image files, 
do I have to write

> img src

twice for each image?

If there is more efficient way to solve this issue, 
it would be really appreciated to remind me of that. thank you.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"> this is enough, this will search in public directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write them twice since you are referring to the same file.

It has to be like this since you have configured your `express static`:

```
//for css file
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css">
//for image.  
<img src="/imagefilepath">
```

The point is that there should be one, not two.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. by the way, what is the difference between css/style.css and /css/style.css ? the first one works well in the views/main/home.ejs but not in the views/sub/intro/location.ejs

Comment: It depends on your folder structure. `css/style.css` means that `css`  is a top-level folder and not inside any folder while `/css/style.css` means that  `css` is inside another folder.